# Fetching Data with cURL (JavaScript, PHP, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, curl

I am learning webdev and programming at college, and want to advance some of the courses, so I'm learning on my own. I'm trying to figure out how APIs work, and I have found this site HabitRPG (http://habitrpg.com) that has an API that works with cURL. SO I'm new in all of this.

I would like to know how to use cURL without the client, so whether in PHP, jQuery or JavaScript.
Here is the API of the site https://github.com/lefnire/habitrpg/wiki/API

Thank you very much

Comment: without client?? can you elaborate your question ??/

Comment: Yes, I saw that you can use a client that allows you to use command lines to send curl commands. But I don't want to use it, I want to fetch the data from HabitRPG and be able to import it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution .Try it once .....

A PHP class for the HabitRPG API.

[HABITRPG](https://github.com/ruddfawcett/HabitRPG_PHP)